# ¿Como obtengo la cantidad de valores de varias Propiedades de un objeto?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto, dentro de ese objeto tengo otros 2 objetos en el que esa la propiedad "edad" y su valor correspondiente. Lo que quiero es obtener las edades de todos las propiedades y verificar la cantidad de personas que tienen menos de 18, he tratado de hacerlo con el "for" y recorrer sus valores, pero no se de que manera hago para contar y guardar todos esos valores y al final saber la cantidad, tipo asi: invitados = [2], (siendo este la cantidad de personas que tiene menos de 18).

```
const cuantosMenores = require('../02.js');
let invitados = {
  Luna: {
    edad: 3,
  },
  Sebas: {
    edad: 13,
  },
  Marce: {
    edad: 23,
  },
  Nicky: {
    edad: 31,
  },
};


let invitados2 = {
  Luna: {
    edad: 3,
  },
  Sebas: {
    edad: 13,
  },
  Marce: {
    edad: 23,
  },
  Nicky: {
    edad: 8,
  },
};
```

//////

**/anexo mi codigo:/**

```
var menoresDeEdad = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < invitados.length; i++){
    if(invitados.edad[i] < 18)
    menoresDeEdad.push(invitados.edad[i]);
  }

  return menoresDeEdad
```

Comment: Eliminé la etiqueta `Java` puesto que la pregunta no está relacionada con dicho lenguaje de programación.

Comment: @E.Betanzos gracias por la correccion, soy nuevo el sitio, se me paso por alto las etiquetas.

Comment: No hay problema Juan, por eso pasamos todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas intentando recorrer un objeto lleno de propiedades, pero sin embargo lo tratas como si fuera un array de objetos.

Una posible solución para recorrer un objeto es usar la instrucción **[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)**.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
// const cuantosMenores = require('../02.js');
let invitados = {
  Luna: {
    edad: 3,
  },
  Sebas: {
    edad: 13,
  },
  Marce: {
    edad: 23,
  },
  Nicky: {
    edad: 31,
  },
};


let invitados2 = {
  Luna: {
    edad: 3,
  },
  Sebas: {
    edad: 13,
  },
  Marce: {
    edad: 23,
  },
  Nicky: {
    edad: 8,
  },
};

var menoresDeEdad = [];

for (const property in invitados) {
  if (invitados[property].edad < 18)
    menoresDeEdad.push(invitados[property].edad);
}

console.log(menoresDeEdad)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias a tu metodo pude llegar a la respuesta. La cuestion era que necesitaba definir un acumulador, entrar a los valores de las propiedades del objeto, poner una condicion a ese acumulador, y de acuerdo vaya cumpliendo la condicion, el acumulador va sumando +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
function obtenerMenores(invitados){
    let menores = 0; // contador
    invitadosArray = Object.values(invitados); // devuelve un array con todos los valores del objeto [Luna{}, Sebas{},Marce{},Nicky{}] en este caso un array de objetos
    invitadosArray.forEach(element => { if(element.edad<18) menores++ }); // para cada objeto verificamos si cumple la condicion de que edad<18 y si es asi incrementamos el contador
    return menores; devolvemos el contador
}

console.log(`Numero de menores invitados 1: ${obtenerMenores(invitados)}`) // imprimimos
console.log(`Numero de menores invitados 2: ${obtenerMenores(invitados2)}`)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por el aporte, pero descubrí que no necesitaba un arreglo, sino simplemente acceder a los valores de las propiedades del objeto utilizando el "forEach", definiendo primero un acumulador, recorrer esos valores y dar una condicion para retornar la cantidad de acuerdo al valor deefinido de estas, de igual gracias por comentar.